# Hysteresis in finite automata

Tags: automata-theory, regular-expressions, memory

The concept of [hysteresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hysteresis) seems well suited to describe and distinguish finite automata:

> "Hysteresis is the dependence of the state of a system on its history." <sub>(Wikipedia, *Hysteresis*)</sub>
>
> "[The state of a finite state machine] is determined by its history.
>   <sub>(Minsky, *Computation*)</sub>

What I am looking for is a definition of hysteresis *strength* $H$ of finite automata distinguishing finite automata with a stronger dependence on history from those with a weaker one.

------------------ *edited* -----------------------

Thanks to domotorp's hint, I found that the [Nerode index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem) is a good such measure: finite automata (equivalent to finite regular expressions) have a finite Nerode index, and the smaller the Nerode index is, the less "memory" (or hysteresis strength) the automaton has.

But: The Nerode index is defined rather abstractly, as the number of equivalence classes of a language with respect to the Nerode equivalence relation.

What I would like to know:

> 1. How is the Nerode index related to the structure/complexity/size of a regular expression?
> 2. How is the Nerode index related to the structure/complexity/size of an equivalent state diagram?

Is there more to say than:

- The lesser complex the regular expression describing an automaton is, the
  smaller its Nerode index is.
- The Nerode index is correlated to the number of (accessible) states.

Comment: You can consider automata s.t. the state is a function of the last $k$ input symbols. However, for some automata no finite $k$ is sufficient.

Comment: What is an automata with memory/what is a memory-less automata? Are you aware of the Myhill-Nerode theorem?

Comment: crossposted on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016512/hysteresis-in-finite-automata

Comment: 1. I tried to sketch how a memory-less automaton might look like. Why doesn't this work?
2. I was not. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: From your question, it seems like you are not understanding the Myhill-Nerode theorem. The number of equivalence classes is exactly equal to the minimum number of states of a DFA recognizing the language. On the other hand, the size of a regular expression corresponds more closely to the size of an NFA, which can be a lot smaller, and for which the theory is not nearly as nice.